# Mule CloudHub-MMC Interation

Tags: mule, cloudhub

We Added our Mule Local server(Local MMC) to the CloudHub using amc-setup. Server added successfully. We started our local MMC and in Cloudhub we are able to see server Running. 
Then we deployed our application into this server and it is deployed successfully.

Now, my question is how to access the application. what is the endpoint???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about Local Mule and Local MMC.
MMC is the Mule Management Console and is your local management application.

You probably are hooking up your Local Mule instance (that runs on-premise) to CloudHub so that you can manage it over there.

All applications will run locally, so the endpoints are local.
HTTP endpoints are hit at the ip address of the local mule instance, CloudHub is just for managing en control.

It's the local Mule agent that runs on the mule instance that connects to CloudHub.